# Centering a single component in angular 8 without effecting the styles of child elements inside that component

Tags: css, angular, frontend

I want to  center div s inside a component without effecting styles of the div s inside that component . How could I do this ?

I am using angular 8 . Text align method effects the alignment of the text inside that div. I want to center elements while preventing that.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your component's template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's lots of ways to center a div and all can be done without impact on child elements. There's a really good list of ways described here:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

For your case the easiest will likely be to add

```
display: flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;
```

For additional help learning flexbox there's a fun game:
https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can add styles to the component `display: flex; justify-content: center`